# how to make docker-compose access external Kafka/Zookeeper, network drives

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm new to Docker and I have the following questions.

1. My app talks to Kafka and I understand the need for a Kafka container for the sake of testing. But, the real Kafka installation exists outside of Docker on its own server. Do I still need a Kafka and Zookeeper Docker containers? Can I just configure my applications' Docker containers to point to the real Kafka and zookeeper? And if not, then how do I give the Kafka/Zookeeper containers access to the real Kafka installation?
2. I read from Docker's documentation that "network_mode: bridge" is the default value, but when I explicitly put that in I get errors of not able to connect to host. That's why I have it commented out, so I'd appreciate if someone can answer me why?
3. My app requires access to an external network shared drive to process files and have read/write permission for those drives. How do I give my containers such access? Right now for testing when I pass a path e.g. c:\myFolder\MyFile.txt, when I try reading the file it gets appended by /app/C:\myFolder\MyFile.txt

Here is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  my.app.api.producer:
    #network_mode: bridge
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}myappapiproducer
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Source/My.App.Api.Producer/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'kafka:9092'
      #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'kafka-manager.my.domain.com:9092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_CONNECTION_URL: 'schema_registry:8081'
      KAFKA_DURABILITY_ACKS: '1'
      TOPIC_NAME_PUB: 'paas.my.app.v1.us-west.dev.in'
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema_registry

  my.app.consoleapp:
    #network_mode: bridge
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}myappconsoleapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Source/My.App.ConsoleApp/Dockerfile
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'kafka:9092'
      #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'kafka-manager.my.domain.com:9092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_CONNECTION_URL: 'schema_registry:8081'
      KAFKA_DURABILITY_ACKS: '1'
      TOPIC_NAME_PUB: 'paas.my.app.v1.us-west.dev.out'
      TOPIC_NAME_SUB: 'paas.my.app.v1.us-west.dev.in'
      KAFKA_ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT: 'false'
      KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS: '60000'
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema_registry

  zookeeper:
    #network_mode: bridge
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    #network_mode: bridge
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    #hostname: kafka
    hostname: kafka-manager.my.domain.com
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  schema_registry:
    #network_mode: bridge
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
    hostname: schema_registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema_registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime-jessie AS base
WORKDIR /app

# Stage 2
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk-jessie AS builder
WORKDIR /src
COPY Source/My.App.ConsoleApp/My.App.ConsoleApp.csproj Source/My.App.ConsoleApp/
COPY Source/My.App.Schemas/My.App.Schemas.csproj Source/My.App.Schemas/
COPY Source/My.App.Domain/My.App.Domain.csproj Source/My.App.Domain/
COPY Source/My.App.PubSub/My.App.PubSub.csproj Source/My.App.PubSub/
RUN dotnet restore Source/My.App.ConsoleApp/My.App.ConsoleApp.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Source/My.App.ConsoleApp
RUN dotnet build My.App.ConsoleApp.csproj -c Release -o /app

# Stage 3 - Testing stage - This is not working, so spend time on making the test stage to work.
FROM builder AS test
WORKDIR /src/Tests/UnitTests/My.App.Domain.UnitTests
RUN dotnet test

# Stage 4
FROM builder AS publish
RUN dotnet publish My.App.ConsoleApp.csproj -c Release -o /app

# Stage 5
FROM base AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "My.App.ConsoleApp.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I just configure my applications' Docker containers to point to the real Kafka and zookeeper?

Yes. If you want to actually read and write to your actual production Kafka environment, you would need to do that.

And your app should ideally not be calling a property `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`, as that means something special for the Kafka Server itself. The Producer and Consumer code use property of `bootstrap.servers`.

> "network_mode: bridge" is the default value, but when I explicitly put that in I get errors of not able to connect to host.

Depends on your Host OS, but you ideally shouldn't need to reach from inside a container to a process/network address on the host anyway. Docker Compose Services can reach each other by their service names. So, in your app code, you would only need `kafka:9092` or `http://schema_registry:8083` (assuming those containers are also running).

Otherwise, when using your actual Kafka server, you need to get those values from the environment variables using the appropriate methods in your code.

> app requires access to an external network shared drive to process files and have read/write permission for those drives. How do I give my containers such access?

You should mount an NFS filesystem in Windows, then you can use a Docker volume for that path.

(note: I have not tested this personally)

```
volumes:
    - X:\SomeRemotePath:/path/inside/container
```

> when I try reading the file it gets appended by /app/C:\myFolder\MyFile.txt

It's not clear from your question where this happens because I do not believe the Confluent Docker images have a `/app` directory and I cannot tell where that file is copied into any other container.

Comment: Thanks bud. As for the '/app' I think that's coming from the WORKDIR in the generated Docker file shown below. And I think it's related because I've made my VS2017 project be Linux Docker instances and I'm passing Windows paths for testing? I can't find a simple way of switching VS projects from Linux to Windows Docker types other than re-creating the projects from scratch.

Comment: And as far as connecting to the real Kafka, what settings do I need to set to make that happen? The environment variable KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS is known only for my app, but thanks for pointing it out, I'll rename it. But, basically the value of this environment variable goes into bootstrap.servers, and when I gave it the hostname and port of the real/prod Kafka server, it didn't connect to it.

Comment: The reason I need to get to an external network, is because there are other legacy standalone services that manage files on certain network locations, and my new Docker based micro services need o access those locations to do something with the files.

Comment: I cannot read those comments... Please edit your initial question to include the Dockerfile as formatted text

Comment: But anyway, `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'external-kafka-1.fqdn.domain:9092,external-kafka-2.fqdn.domain:9092'` should work absolutely fine within a container. At least from all the testing I have done with in (from a Mac)

Comment: Sorry, Dockerfile added.

Comment: Does this BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS setting need to go directly under my application's container settings, or under the kafka container's?

And this is just an environment variable right?

Comment: `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` would be the environment variable key. How you get that in C#, I am not sure, but it's just a rename of your current `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` value